# Non Compact Amenable group does not have Property (FH)

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, locally-compact-groups

I'm learning from some notes about Analytic Group Theory and I'm stuck on an exercise there.

Prove that a non compact Amenable group does not have Property (FH).

At this point of the notes we learned about Amenability and know the following equivalence:

1. $G$ is amenable (has a finite additive, finite left (or right or both) invariant measure defined on all subsets.
2. $G$ has a left (or right or both) invariant mean.
3. $G$ admits almost invariant functions in $L^p(G)$.
4. Any Hausdorff Compact space such that $G$ acts on it continuously admits a $G$-invariant Borel measure.
5. Any compact convex set such that $G$ acts on it with affine transformations has a fixed point.

The only thing we know about (FH) property is the definition:
A group has property (FH) if any isometric action of it on a Hilbert space admits a fixed point.

Later on in the notes it is proven that property (T) and property (FH) are (almost) equivalent. I don't want to use that (I think that's cheating because the exercise was given before).

Thank you

Comment: Yes, there is a direct construction of a proper affine isometric action of any amenable group on a Hilbert space. You can find it in the book on a-T-menability.

Comment: Thank you! What's the name of the book?

Comment: Groups with the Haagerup Property. Gromov’s a-T-menability. https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783034894869