# What is the relationship between amenability and property (T)?

Tags: functional-analysis, group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I'm viewing Chapter 10 of [GTM276](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-58540-6) which focuses on some properties of topological groups including amenability and property (T). A footnote says they are almost exclusive. What does it mean? Does it mean that if a group has amenability then it will likely not have property (T)? I guess it true because we can see the difference on associated Cayley graphs: Amenability implies few connectivity while property (T) guarantees certain connectivity.

Comment: A group is simultaneously amenable and have propriety (T) if and only if it is compact.

Comment: For locally compact Hausdorff groups (e.g. for discrete groups that you seem to be interested in), as Ruy noted, amenability plus Property (T) implies compactness. You will find a proof pretty much in any book that deals with Property (T): It follows from the representation-theoretic interpretation of both properties. See e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173429/non-compact-amenable-group-does-not-have-property-fh) question.

Comment: @Richard Chen To add to these useful comments, there is a whole book that deals with property (T). Look up "Kazhdan’s Property (T)" by B. Bekka, P. de la Harpe and A. Valette. The appendix of this book in itself is a very useful resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof that amenability + property (T) implies compactness is actually straightforward:  If the locally compact group
$G$ is amenable, then the left regular representation is faithful, hence it *weakly* contains the trivial
representation ($g→1$).  From property (T) it then follows that the regular representation *truly* contains the trivial
representation.  This means that there is some $f$ in $L^2(G)$ that is fixed  under all left translations,
hence $f$ must be constant.  However if a constant function is square integrable, the underlying measure, namely Haar
measure, must be finite.  Finally, it is well known that Haar measure is only finite on compact groups.